# Getting custom output from numtoname

Tags: memoir, conversion, number

We can expand digits to words in memoir class using numtoname command. But when I expand 125000 using numtoname, I get an output one hundred and twenty-five thousands. Instead I would like to get an output as One lac twenty five thousand. How can I do it?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{numtoname}

\date{February 2022}

\begin{document}
\numtoname{125000}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```tex
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
\numtoname{125000}

\renewcommand*\nNamec{\iflowernumtoname l\else L\fi ac}

\numtoname{125000}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Every word that would appear in the output of `\numtoname`, like "one" and "hundred", is stored in a separate macro, hence configurable. Not all these macros are documented but one can find it in `memoir.cls`

Comment: Errors with this approach. 1250 is expanded to one thousand two lac fifty with this approach

Comment: @Vaibhav Ah, simple renaming won't work here. One has to patch the internal parser.